# Check A Check-Box on 3rd Party Site Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Google Chrome Extension that will *automatically check the 3rd checkbox (Hansen Dam)* on a 3rd party website. I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the website:
https://cityofla.ezlinksgolf.com/index.html#/preSearch

**manifest.json**

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Tester",
"version": "1.0.0",
"permissions": ["activeTab"],
  
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": ["Scripts/content.js"]
  }
]
}
```

**content.js**

```
// trying to check the 3rd box directly, method 1
const a=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
a[3].checked = true;



// i've tried checking all the boxes with a loop, method 2
var arr = [];
const allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (let i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++){
    if (allInputs[i].type == 'checkbox')
      allInputs[i].checked = true;
      arr.push(i);  // make a new array of only checkboxes, to pick 3rd checkbox from this array
}

// trying another way, method 3
arr[3].checked = true;
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need the `<all_urls>` permission to automatically inject your content script. `activeTab` allows you to inject scripts only when you click on the extension's icon. Also remember that arrays are zero-based, so the third element of array `a` is `a[2]`, not `a[3]`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even with the <all_urls> it doesn't work. No boxes will be checked regardless of which a[x] is chosen. I thought maybe it needed to be run after the page loads, so also tried using "run_at": "document_end", but this didn't work either.

Comment: Interestingly, if I turn the code into a bookmarklet, then it will successfully check the box I want. Any reason why this works for bookmarklet but not as a chrome extension?

Comment: For example, this works (where the 3rd checkbox's value is 5995):   javascript:function getCheckboxByValue(v) {var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].value == v) {return inputs[i];}}return false;}const aa = getCheckboxByValue(5995);aa.checked = true;